# If having lived and worked some years in the UK, how do I estimate the actual expected state pension amount?

Tags: united-kingdom, pension

The UK government has a [state pension forecast calculator](https://www.gov.uk/check-state-pension).  The calculation has a footnote informing the user that it assumes the user will continue paying in for the rest of their working life.  This may apply to most/all people in the UK, but not to me, for I have left permanentl.  Overall, I have spent time in Sweden, Canada, UK, and Germany.  If I'm not mistaken, those countries mutually recognise each other's state pension insurance systems for the purposes of counting contribution years (meaning I reach the 10 years minimum despite having lived/worked in the UK for less than 10 years), but, as I understand it, each country pension system will still pay out individually.  Considering I have lived and worked x years in the UK in the past, how do I estimate from the gov.uk "this is the most you could get" the amount I might *actually* expect to get after I reach the UK retirement age?

Answer (score 1):

You can contact the Department of Works and Pensions and get a State Pension Statement. This will tell you how much pension you will get based on the contributions you have so far, and will not include future contributions.

Canada for one does **not** treat UK contributions as adding to Canadian years of contribution. I would strongly advise you to look into making voluntary pension contributions in the UK even if you are not living there. But both of those a subjects too complex to discuss here and worthy of questions in their own right.

Comment: NB: I've only lived/worked in Canada for 15 months and didn't earn much there, so I'm not too bothered about the Canadian component. I don't know about the UK, but [Germany and Canada have an agreement](https://www.deutsche-rentenversicherung.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/DE/Broschueren/international/weitere_abkommen/15_arbeiten_deutschland_kanada.html) at least, and I strongly expect to remain in Germany and may swap Dutch for German citizenship at some point.